# CSS: How to position a panel slightly off the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I'm having a problem moving a panel slightly of the page like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNDRb.png)

I tried `width: 120%`

it does work but when I resize the image moves out of its original position, I'd like it to look similar on different screens, the panel is inside the bootstrap 4 container coz I use bootstrap 4

Pls help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick pen that might help you. [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/craig_codes/pen/qBqyaJR) If you create a pen or share your code I'll take a look for you mines just a rough idea but might help you.

If you are trying to get the image off the right of the screen use `margin-right: -???px` but make sure you have `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code to try and reproduce the problem on our end, I would assume that you need to set the width of the margin-left depending on the viewport. This means that with different viewports you need to adjust the margin accordingly.

Check this out based on device size.

```
/* For devices smaller than 400px: */
body {
  left-margin: 100%;
}

/* For devices 400px and larger: */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) {
  body {
    left-margin: 50%;
  }
}
```

Take a look at W3's Informative Series on responsive web design.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp